# How to make a nan-like class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a class such that any interaction with an instance of it returns another instance of that class. This would be similar to how nans interact with other numbers:

```
import numpy as np
np.nan + 3
Out[3]: nan
```

But it would apply to any python object:

```
nan_like + [3,2,1]
Out[4]: nan_like
```

as well as any operation:

```
nan_like[10]
Out[5]: nan_like
```

The best I have come up with so far is:

```
import numpy as np

class NanLike(np.lib.mixins.NDArrayOperatorsMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return NanLike()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "NanLike"
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "NanLike"
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return NanLike()

    def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs):
        return NanLike()
    
    def __array_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs):
        return NanLike()




nan_like = NanLike()


print(nan_like + [3,2,1])

print(nan_like[10])
```

Which does indeed behave like I want it to. But in my application it is possible that I can end up with quite a few of these objects. Is that wise? I've looked into making it a singleton like the None object, but there seems to be a strong stance against singletons with people saying that the need for a singleton is an indicator of bad architecture and I don't want to push forward if what I am trying to do is inherently bad.

Comment: What is this for, more broadly?

Comment: A singleton is fine if it acts like a constant and isn‘t some kind of state container. Not sure why anyone would want *more* NaN-like values, though :P

Comment: @AMC I have a data structure that when interacting with other instances of it can be "expanded" so that they have the same length and I need a filler value. Similar to numpy arrays, but my data structure can have any type.